# past my car on both sides

Tags: meaning

> *In late winter, after an early-morning Crossfit workout, I sit quietly in my car. The next class, sprinting to warm up, races out of the gym and past my car on both sides.*

The Source: J. C. Herz: Learning to breath fire… Page xi.
[LINK](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0385348878)

Could you please help me with the meaning of the second clause. How shall I read it?

*The next class – sprinting to warm up – races out of the gym…*

or

*The next class: sprinting to warm up…*

What does it mean "past my car on both sides"? Thank you.

Comment: @StoneyB -- Oops.  I missed that the first three times I read the sentence.

Answer (score 5):

The first of your two options is correct.

> The next class, sprinting to warm up, races out of the gym and past my car on both sides.

So *sprinting to warm up* is an appositive phrase.  It's being used to describe the class of Crossfit students. Removing it from the sentence doesn't change the meaning, just reduces the level of description.

This leaves:

> The next class races out of the gym and past my car on both sides.

This is a two-item list of actions and the verb *races* is transitive to both phrases. It could be rewritten as:

> The next class races out of the gym.
>
> It [the next class] races past my car on both sides.

---

So, now we've addressed most of the sentence. Hopefully the last part is easier to understand but, just in case it isn't.

> The next class races past my car on both sides.

The *past my car on both sides* means that there was a group of students and, in order to get to their destination, they were going past while he was sitting in his car.  Because of where he was, some of the students were passing on the left side of the car and others on the right.

Imagine it as if his car was a small island in the middle of a river with the students being the water.

> *The water flows past the island **on both sides***.